# Replace characters in string with values

Tags: vb.net, string, replace

I have a string which is a paragraph written on the aspx side. It goes like this:

> The new student, {student_name} has the following grades -
>   Maths - {math_grade}
>   Science - {Science_grade}
>   ...
>   and so on.

I need to get values from database, and replace `{student_name}` with `Joe Smith`, `{Math_grade}` wth `A` or `B+` etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

[String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim myString As String = "{student_name}"

myString = myString.Replace("{student_name}","Joe Smith")
```

...Remember to always assign the string you are attempting to replace values in to the original string.

`myString.Replace("value","newvalue")`

...will not replace your original strings values -- it must be explicitly assigned. e.g.

```
myString = myString.Replace("value","newvalue")
```

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can use String.Replace, but typically ASP.NET apps are written using labels as placeholders and then modifying the values in the code-behind.

So your MyFile.aspx would contain
The new student, [lblStudentName] has the following grades - Maths - [lblMathGrade] Science - [lblScienceGrade] ... and so on

**Then in your MyFile.aspx.cs (or MyFile.aspx.vb)**

```
this.lblStudentName.Text = "John Doe";
this.lblMathGrade.Text = "A-";
this.lblScienceGrade.Text = "F";
```

There are also many other better techniques you could use, such as a repeater control, then binding the sql results to this control.