# Replace bad words in ListBox

Tags: vb.net, string, replace, listbox

Can someone tell me how can I remove the bad words from listbox?

Example I have an item "Sh*t hats" But i would like to replace "Sh*t" with nothing. How can I do this? I tried:

```
ListBox1.Items.Item(1).remove("Sh*t")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [vb.net replace characters in string with values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407957/vb-net-replace-characters-in-string-with-values)

Comment: You need the [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) function.

Comment: You could do it manually, by make a list of all of them with their replaced values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7430168/62576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you add the ListBox items, if they are just strings, this should work:

```
For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    If ListBox1.Items(i).ToString.Contains("badword") Then
        ListBox1.Items(i) = ListBox1.Items(i).ToString.Replace("badword", "")
    End If
Next
```

(do note its case sensitive), you could use `ListBox1.Items(i) = ListBox1.Items(i).ToString.ToLower.Replace("badword", "")` but this will mean any item that gets changed will be turned into all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

This example creates a Generic List of strings with badwords on it, loops through the listbox,  compares with the badword list, and removes if found:

```
Dim BadWords As New List(Of String)
BadWords.Add("poop")
BadWords.Add("crap")
For Each li As ListItem In Me.ListBox1.Items
   If BadWords.Contains(li.Text) Then
       li.Text = ""
   End If
Next
```

With every iteration, `li` is an actual instance of the `ListBox's` `ListItem` element, so modifying it right then and there, would also update it in the list.

Comment: using a `List(Of String)` is a useful method, however i found that with a `ListBox` i could not loop over the items and use the reference like that as the items would not update properly, as for `ListItem` are you referring to [System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) ?

Comment: I tested this code before I posted it. Yes, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem are the items in a ListBox.

Comment: ah, i see you are using the [System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx) while i was using [System.Windows.Controls.ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.aspx) that could have been the reason why the behavior was diffrent.

Comment: @Ahhh, my bad hahaha  I was engaged in WebMode.